# Why is ListBoxFor not selecting items, but ListBox is?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(c => c.Project.Categories,
        new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name", new List<int> { 1, 2 }))%>

<%= Html.ListBox("MultiSelectList", 
        new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name", new List<int> { 1, 2 }))%>
```

The only difference is that the first helper is strongly typed (ListBoxFor), and **it fails to show the selected items** (1,2), even though the items appear in the list, etc. The simpler ListBox is working as expected.

I'm obviously missing something here. I can use the second approach, but this is really bugging me and I'd like to figure it out.

For reference, my model is:

```
public class ProjectEditModel
{
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public ProjectSlide SelectedSlide { get; set; }
}
```

### Update

I just changed the ListBox name to Project.Categories (matching my model) and it now FAILS to select the item.

```
<%= Html.ListBox("Project.Categories",
        new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name", new List<int> { 1, 2 }))%>
```

I'm obviously not understanding the magic that is happening here.

### Update 2

Ok, this is purely naming, for example, this works...

```
<%= Html.ListBox("Project_Tags",
new MultiSelectList(Model.Tags, "Id", "Name", Model.Project.Tags.Select(t => t.Id)))%>
```

...because the field name is Project_Tags, not Project.Tags, in fact, anything other than Tags or Project.Tags will work. I don't get why this would cause a problem (other than that it matches the entity name), and I'm not good enough at this to be able to dig in and find out.

Comment: I was having a similar problem. Specifically though I was setting my selected value for the list box (on the model) from within the controller based on another value. To get this to work, I have to set the ModelState["Categories"].Value. I don't like this, but the idea that the ModelState object can be used over the Model itself is confusing at best, infuriating at worst.

Answer (score 26):

I've stumbled across this problem myself, finally I realized that the problem was a naming convention.

You cannot name the ViewBag or ViewData poperty containing the SelectList or MultiSelectList to the same name your property model containing the selected items. At least not if you're using the ListBoxFor or DropDownListFor helper.

Here's an example:

```
    public class Person
    {
          public List<int> Cars { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
          //wont work
          ViewBag.Cars = new SelectList(carsList, "CarId", "Name"); 

          //will work due to different name than the property.
          ViewBag.CarsList = new SelectList(carsList, "CarId", "Name"); 

          return View();
    }

    //View
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Cars, ViewBag.CarsList as SelectList)
```

I'm sure theres plenty of other ways doing this, but it solved my problem, hope it will help someone!

Comment: Thanks Olivier, that fixed it.  That is really stupid because when I create regular select list items in the ViewBag I put them as the same name and they work great.

Answer (score 3):

I have also been stuck with this exact same issue and encountered the same problem with ListBox and ListBoxFor.

No matter what I do, I cannot get selections to occur on the ListBoxFor. If I change to the ListBox and name it something OTHER than the property name of the data I am binding to, selections occur.

But then because I'm not using ListBoxFor and the data is sitting inside a model class (Model.Departments) for example, I don't get model binding on the way back to my controller and hence the property is null.

*EDIT* I found a solution posted by someone else here;
[Challenges with selecting values in ListBoxFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194143/challenges-with-selecting-values-in-listboxfor/3195986#3195986)

Comment: Darn, I wish I could remember the fix for this. If I remember correctly, it isn't as elegant as I'd like. There is an obscure behavior that is happening with model binding that causes your bind to be overridden. Not nice. If I can find an example I will share.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can try to clear ModelState for c.Project.Categories in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ModelType model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("Project.Categories");
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

And use the next construction:

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(c => c.Project.Categories,
        new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"))%>
```

Where c.Project.Categories is `IEnumerable<int>`.

Sorry for my english. Good luck!

Comment: I think that this is the best answer here. Here is why: Looking at the HtmlHelper ListBox source one can see that the code **first tries to grab the Selected values from the controller ModelState**, and ONLY if it is NULL then it will use the selected values supplied in the MultiSelectList. ==> So if you want to override the values stored in the ModelState (e.g. values sent from the browser to the Controller), clearing the MoelState is the way to go.

Comment: Source code is [here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/mvc3/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs) line 173

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is that it doesn't work very well. As such I read the MVC code. What you need to do is implement IConvertible and also create a TypeConverter.

So, in my instance I had a `Country` class, such that people could choose from a list of countries. No joy in selecting it.  I was expecting an object equals comparison on the `selectedItems` against the `listitems` but no, that's not how it works. Despite the fact that `MultiListItem` works and correctly gets the selected items, the moment it is bound to your model it's all based on checking that the string represnetation of your object instance matches the string `"value"` (or name if that is missing) in the list of items in the `SelectItemList`.

So, implement `IConvertible`, return the string value from `ToString` which would match the value in the `SelectItemList`. e.g in my case `CountryCode` was serialized into the `SelectItem` `Value` property , so in `ToString IConvertible` I returned `CountryCode`.  Now it all selects correctly.

I will point out the `TypeConverter` is used on the way in. This time its the inverse. That `Countrycode` comes back in and "EN" needs converting into `Country` class instance. That's where the `TypeConverter` came in. It's also about the time I realised how difficult this approach is to use.

p.s so on your `Category` class you need to implement `IConvertible`. If its from the entity framework as my company is then you'll need to use the partial class to implement `IConvertible` and implement `ToString` and decorate it with a `TypeConverter` you wrote too.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't an answer to your main question, it is worth noting that when MVC generates names it will turn something like Project.Tags into Project_Tags, replacing periods with underscores.

The reason that it does this is because a period in an element ID would look like an element named Project with a class of Tags to CSS. Clearly a bad thing, hence the translation to underscores to keep behaviour predictable.

In your first example,

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(c => c.Project.Categories,
    new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name", new List<int> { 1, 2 }))%>
```

the listbox is attempting to bind to Model.Project.Categories for your strongly typed Model which has been provided to the page (using the lambda notation). I'm not sure what the second parameter in the ListBoxFor is doing though.

What is the Model that is being passed to the page?

Comment: At your request, I've added my model to the question.

I'm aware that MVC changes the Id to Id="Project_Tags", but not so with the name, it remains "Project.Tags", and the name is what is posted back to the action, and therefore, I guess the part that is causing trouble, hence, if I change to Project_Tags, for the name property, it works. I'm just surprised there is even a strongly typed listboxfor helper if it really can't be used for multiselect lists!

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(c => c.Project.Categories,
    new MultiSelectList(
        Model.Categories
        ,"Id"
        ,"Name"
        ,Model.Project.Tags.Select(
        x => new SelectListItem()
            {
            Selected = true,
            Text = x.TEXT,
            Value = x.ID.ToString()
            }).ToList())

       )
)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Html.ListboxFor and Html.Listbox work great when you're NOT binding the list box to its data source. I assume the intended use is this:

```
// Model
public class ListBoxEditModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> SelectedCategories { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCategories,
                 new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"))
// or, equivalently
@Html.ListBox("SelectedCategories" ,
                 new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name"))
```

Note that in this case you don't have to explicitly say which values are selected in the MultiSelectList - the model you're binding to takes precedence, even if you do!