# confused by ASP.NET MVC Html.ListBoxFor(...) SelectExtension

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Like [this poster](http://goo.gl/5cQVl), I'm a bit confused by ASP.NET MVC Html.ListBoxFor(...).  Specifically I'm putting the selection results in a List but after I post the results I'm getting

```
InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedDeclarations' is of type 'System.String[]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'
```

Here is my abbreviated ViewModel that I'm passing to the strongly-typed razor view

```
public MyViewModel 
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        (...)
        this.VendorsRequiringDeclaration = new List<SelectListItem>();
        this.SelectedDeclarations = new List<String>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<String> SelectedDeclarations { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> VendorsRequiringDeclaration { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the view code that references them

```
      @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedDeclarations, Model.VendorsRequiringDeclaration, new { @class="editor-field", @size=6})
```

If I change MyViewModel such that SelectedDeclarations is a List of SelectedListItem rather than a List of String, upon post to the appropriate controller action it thinks my model is invalid:

```
{"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."}
```

Ideas?  I probably have the wrong LINQ expression for the first parameter, but I can't see it from the similar questions.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look for this question, it might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308846/why-is-listboxfor-not-selecting-items-but-listbox-is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `ModelState` is not valid, you need to reset the `ViewData` object inside the controller.

Since data inside `VendorsRequiringDeclaration` is not saved anywhere.

Comment: I tried adding these to the controller method that launches the view

this.ModelState.Remove("SelectedDeclarations");
this.ModelState.Remove("VendorsRequiringDeclaration");

but these are not part of ModelState in the controller action that launches the view, although they are in the model that is passed to the view.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the problem was SQL permissions on an underlying data table that I am accessing via EF; the post failed and made it appear to be the Html Helper -- apologies for any confusion!

Based on AlexanderB's suggestion though I did rework the Html.ListBoxFor(...) thusly, and it seems to work fine:

```
             @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedDeclarations,
                              new MultiSelectList(
                              Model.VendorsRequiringDeclaration,
                              "Id",
                              "VendorName",
                              Model.VendorsRequiringDeclaration.Select(
                                 x => new SelectListItem()
                                          {
                                              Selected = false,
                                              Text = x.VendorName,
                                              Value = x.Id.ToString()
                                          }).ToList()),
                          new { @class = "editor-field", @size = 6 } )
```