# How to add an object to a listbox by clicking on checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, listbox

I have a form with a list of checkboxes and a listbox.

I need that when you check or uncheck a checkbox, it modifies the list in the listBox by adding or removing an object in the list. This is how it looks:

[image]

Here is the code for that part of the form:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span3">
                                     <label>Fonction(s):</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span9">                                        
                                    @Html.ListBoxFor(contact => contact.SelectedFonctionIds, Model.ListeFonctionsSelectList, new { disabled = "disabled" })                                
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span5 offset3">
                                    <div class="fonctions_container">
                                            @foreach (extranetClient.Models.Classes.FonctionContact fonction in ViewBag.Fonctions)
                                            {
                                                string coche = "";
                                                if ((@Model.ListeFonctions).Any(c => c.IdFonction == fonction.IdFonction))
                                                {
                                                    coche = "checked";
                                                }

                                                <input type="checkbox" @coche id="@fonction.LibelleFonction" onclick="javascript:AjouterFonction();" value="@fonction.IdFonction" />@fonction.LibelleFonction <br />
                                            }
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Does anyone knows how to do that?

I was thinking about Ajax but the thing is that it's a strongly typed view and all the datas are associated to a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is a good solution but what if you put your listbox into a partial view (strongly typed as well), and then your AjouterFonction() JavaScript would make an Ajax call to an Action which returns a PartialView containing updated version of that listbox? Then you use jQuery to replace the previous listbox for the new one.

Controller action:

```
public PartialViewResult ActionName(<whatever you need here>)
{
    // Whatever logic you may need: which item was clicked, what should be added to the model object, etc....
    return PartialView("ListBoxPartial", yourModelObject);
}
```

Partial View ListBoxPartial:

```
@model YourModel
@Html.ListBoxFor(contact => contact.SelectedFonctionIds, Model.ListeFonctionsSelectList, new {disabled = "disabled" })
```

In your View, instead of

```
<div class="span9">                                        
    @Html.ListBoxFor(contact => contact.SelectedFonctionIds, Model.ListeFonctionsSelectList, new { disabled = "disabled" })                                
</div>
```

you'd have:

```
<div class="span9">                                        
   @Html.Partial("ListBoxPartial", Model)                        
</div>
```

Your AjouterFonction(), after receiving the new listbox, AjouterFonction() searches for the div with class "span9" and replaces its contents with the received data.

There may be a better way of solving this, but this was the first thing that popped into my mind.

Comment: Yah why not, interesting, I'll check it out and give you feedbacks

Comment: Ok, in the end let me know how you did it.

Comment: it works but at the end, when I submit the whole form, the selectedFonctionIds are not associated to the contact...

Comment: It is not binding correctly. Can you show me the generated html mark-up? Also, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966201/listboxfor-not-binding-my-viewmodel

Comment: I've tried what they said in the link but nothing more happened. I show you the generated mark-up of the partial view: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hubz/8BfZF/)

Comment: Also I've posted a post which resumes my problem here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203661/view-not-binding-correcty-with-the-model)